# How can I create a SeekBarPreference with 2 thumbs?

Tags: android, xml, kotlin

I need to create a [`SeekBarPreference`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/preference/SeekBarPreference.html) with 2 thumbs (min/max functionality).

There are very, very little resources to find on this - mostly just old broken libraries.

I'd like to implement my own. The backend functionality is not a problem - my problem is trying to create the xml widget. Initially I tried to overlay 2 `SeekBars` on top of eachother but it doesn't seem feasible as only one can be changed at a time.

I'm after direction/a set of steps to implement this `RangeBar` as there is quite a lot to take on.

Alternatively if there are any current libraries with 2-thumb widget,  that are compatible with AndroidX, that would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer below link :

https://github.com/syedowaisali/crystal-range-seekbar

Using this crystal range seekbar library you can modify the seekbar as per your requirements like single thumb or two thumbs and also modify the theme.

[image]

```
<com.crystal.crystalrangeseekbar.widgets.CrystalRangeSeekbar
            android:id="@+id/PriceRangeSeekbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_10ssp"
            app:bar_color="#dddddd"
            app:bar_highlight_color="@color/colorPrimary"
            app:corner_radius="1"
            app:data_type="_integer"
            app:left_thumb_color="@color/white"
            app:left_thumb_image="@drawable/ic_thumb"
            app:max_value="500"
            app:min_value="50"
            app:right_thumb_color="@color/white"
            app:right_thumb_image="@drawable/ic_thumb"
            app:steps="50" />
```

Comment: I wouldn't downvote your answer, as this is a library that promises to do exactly what the OP essentially wants, but others might, as the question does mention doing it without the use of a library.

Comment: I don't think this is compatible with androidx. I copy pasted your xml into my `preferences.xml` (as well as added `implementation 'com.crystal:crystalrangeseekbar:1.1.3'` to my dependencies) - but I'm getting this error: `Binary XML file line #31: Error inflating class com.crystal.crystalrangeseekbar.widgets.CrystalRangeSeekbar` @Sagar